# Extracting Pure Text from an HTML File

Tags: c, parsing

Good Day, I hope you can help me. I have to write this code (in C) that downloads the page source of a website and save it to an html file (I already have done this). The next part is to extract the text from that site, using the saved html file.

I have this algorithm steps in my mind:

Say we have an html file containing:

< something here >< start >< text > Hello < text >   BYE!   < end >

1. Find the "" string, skip the "" string. (this can be implemented with strstr())
2. Set the pointer to the first ">" of "". (use strchr()??)
3. Check if next character in the string is "<": (ignores white spaces)
   a.) If yes, set pointer to next ">". Repeat Check (3).
   b.) If no, get the string until the next "<". Then store (append) it to a big String.
4. Lastly, I'd like to save the String to a file.txt. (fwite? or the option a+ in the fopen()).

Logically, this is correct right?
As a beginner in programming, I always get errors. I have written a code, but it always results to segmentation fault.

Please help me/tell me what is wrong with my code: 
Dummy - file containing html codes

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int get_fileSize(FILE*);

    int main(){

        FILE *dummy = fopen("Dummy2","r");

        int filesize = get_fileSize(dummy);
        printf("Size of dummy = %d Bytes.\n", filesize);

        char *newString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*))*(filesize));

        if(dummy){
            fread(newString, sizeof(char*), filesize, dummy);
        }   

        char *tempString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*))*(filesize));
        char *finalString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*))*(filesize));
        finalString = "\0";

        tempString = strtok(newString, "<");
        do{

            //printf("%s\n",tempString);
            tempString = strtok(NULL, ">");

            if(tempString[1]!='<'){
                    sprintf(finalString,"%s%s",finalString,tempString);            
            }else continue;

        }while(*(newString++)!='\0');

        puts(finalString);

        return 0;
    }

    int get_fileSize(FILE *dummy){

        int size;
        struct stat file;
        fstat(fileno(dummy), &file);
        size = file.st_size;

        return size;

    }
```

Comment: One does not simply parse HTML

Comment: What exactly are the HTML elements you want to extract? Why aren't you using a library that can parse HTML/XML?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, as much as possible I don't want to use those libraries sir. I'm still learning C and I'm instructed to do this the classic way first.

Comment: "the classic way" IS to use standard-libraries (that is, not to implement the wheel a second time). The other option would be to glance at the standard library, extract the interface, and implement the bodies for yourself as a matter of learning. You should always wear a hat labled "system developer" or "application developer" and distinguish between both, and do not mix them.

Comment: You should consider changing the question's name to note that you want to implementment it without libraries. It is a common question as worded but you want an uncommon answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first error, from a glance at your code is that you do `sizeof(char*)` instead of just `char`

```
char *newString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*))*(filesize));
```

should be

```
char *newString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char))*(filesize));
```

You don't want pointers in your string, but `char`s.

You `malloc` the above and never call `free(newString)`, which means you have at least 1 leak, probably more.

Same here:

```
fread(newString, sizeof(char*), filesize, dummy);
```

should be:

```
fread(newString, sizeof(char), filesize, dummy);


finalString = "\n"; //reassigns the pointer to another string, doesn't write into allocated memory.
```

Use `strcpy` to copy strings into allocated memory.

Comment: Thank You Sir! I'll note this. I'll try it later when I code in Ubuntu. I'm currently in Windows now.

Comment: Technically, neither can cause a seg fault: char* is larger than char, thus more memory is allocated. Also you can not read beyond eof thus fread is legitimate too. There are other errors in the code, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code, which are more severe than mentioned in Tony The Lion's answer. Consider this:

```
    char *tempString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*))*(filesize));
    char *finalString = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*))*(filesize));
    finalString = "\0";
    tempString = strtok(newString, "<");
```

The last two lines effectively render first two useless. You re-assign constant strings to variables. When you then `sprintf` to the `finalString`, you get a sig fault since string is constant (and is stored in a static memory that has predefined size - 1 char).

I'd advise using some standart parsing library. You must note that HTML is not always properly formatted, allows nested tags, some text must be ignored (such as inside `script`, `style` tags and so on).

If you still want to do it yourself, you'd better walk through the input, keeping track of whether you are inside a tag, skipping these chars, or inside plaintext, adding this text to something like your finalString.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the file size, use it to control the loop (reading a file doesn't assure there will be a zero byte at the end of what you read):

```
for (toggle = 0, i = 0; i < filesize; ++i) {
      if      (filearray[ i ] == '<')                toggle = 1;
      else if (filearray[ i ] == '>' && toggle != 0) toggle = 0;
      else if (!toggle) {
           printf("\nText char '%c' at %d", filearray[ i ], i);
      }
}
```